# Download openCL 1.2 for windows 10 on NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 1050

Tags: c++, windows, opencl, nvidia

Could someone help me with the process of downloading opencl 1.2 on windows 10 with Nvidia geforce gtx 1050?

I downloaded the latest version of my nvidia graphics card, but when I look into its folders its shows an empty folder for openCL.

Should I be downloading any sdk's for nvidia? If yes where can I find it? I am able to find the nvidia openCL page here https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl but not sure which one to select

Comment: I am using google chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenCL 1.2 runtime is already included in the graphics driver. There is no need to download any other software. You don't need any SDK.
For OpenCL development you will only need the OpenCL header files, see [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57017982/9178992).