# How do I download opencl on linux?

Tags: opencl

I have found several solutions on how to download opencl. But ultimately I have to run the command
"/opt/rocm/opencl/bin/x86_64/clinfo" and end up with the error code "bash: /opt/rocm/opencl/bin/x86_64/clinfo: No such file or directory". So my question is how do I correctly install opencl and so that it is callable in this manner?

Comment: OpenCL is not installed by default. That is why you are seeing the message. Each vendor provides their own version of opencl that comes with their opencl package. You need to download and install the opencl package of the particular vendor. If you are using AMD gpu then you need to install the opencl package that comes with their own version of runtime and driver. You need to install both and then if you query the clinfo, you would be able to get the device details.

Comment: This is an `opencl` question (added), and has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `pytorch` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1):

The OpenCL runtime is installed alongside your graphics driver. There is no need to install anything else to run OpenCL programs. For OpenCL development, you need to download and include the [OpenCL C++ header files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57017982/9178992). The program `clinfo` is just a tool to identify your hardware, but you don't need it. To install it, use `sudo apt-get install clinfo`.