# OpenCL development under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opencl, vendor-neutrality

I want to develop an OpenCL based application with host code in C, using Ubuntu.

But the development packages overwhelm me:

```
$ apt-cache search opencl | grep dev
ocl-icd-dev - Development files to build a ICD Loader
ocl-icd-opencl-dev - OpenCL development files
beignet-dev - OpenCL for Intel GPUs (development files and documentation)
libarrayfire-cpu-dev - Development files for ArrayFire (CPU backend)
libarrayfire-dev - Common development files for ArrayFire
libarrayfire-opencl-dev - Development files for ArrayFire (OpenCL backend)
libarrayfire-unified-dev - Development files for ArrayFire (unified backend)
libasl-dev - development files for ASL
libclblas-dev - development files for clBLAS
libclc-dev - OpenCL C language implementation - development files
libclfft-dev - development files for clFFT
libforge-dev - development files for forge
libgpuarray-dev - development files for libgpuarray
libigc-dev - Intel graphics compiler for OpenCL -- core development files
libigdfcl-dev - Intel graphics compiler for OpenCL -- OpenCL development files
libigdgmm-dev - Intel Graphics Memory Management Library -- development files
liboclgrind-dev - development files for Oclgrind
libopencl-clang-dev - thin wrapper for clang -- development files
libopentk-cil-dev - Open Toolkit wrapper for OpenGL, OpenAL and OpenCL - Dev files
libpocl-dev - development files for the pocl library
librandom123-dev - parallel random numbers library
libviennacl-dev - Scientific computing library written in C++ based on OpenCL
oclgrind - OpenCL device simulator
opencl-clhpp-headers - C++ headers for OpenCL development
nvidia-opencl-dev - NVIDIA OpenCL development files
```

Can I just pick the nvidia opencl-dev, or do I need a different package? I'll be debugging on nVidia, but I want it to run on AMD as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any of them. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63843232/9178992).