# CL/cl.hpp: No such file or directory | NVIDIA GeForce

Tags: c++, opencl, opencl-c, opencl-c++

Good afternoon!
I'm trying to run code in **C++** that has the following line:

```
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
```

But launching the program gives this error:

```
fatal error: CL/cl.hpp: No such file or directory
```

*What have I tried to do?*

1. Completely reinstalling **mingw64**
2. Uninstalled **Visual Studio 2019** and installed **Visual Studio 2022**
3. Installed **NVIDIA Cuda** according to the instructions (I also updated the NVIDIA drivers):
   https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html

Cuda is fully operational. I checked with the code examples that come with CUDA.

P.S. As far as I know, OpenCl is part of CUDA.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you did not add the include path. `#include <CL/cl.hpp>` will only work if your compiler has the folder containing the CL folder in its list of Include directories.

Comment: Thanks! How can i do this? I use mingw64.

Comment: `-I` sets the include directory on that compiler. How you set that depends on how you are building.

Comment: So i need to build it like: g++ file.cpp -I ?

Comment: Or: g++ file.cpp -I cl.hpp

Comment: Related: [https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-i.html](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-i.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to include the OpenCL headers in the same directory where the source code of your Visual Studio Project is. You then have to tell Visual Studio where these files are located. To configure the project and set the file paths, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57017982/9178992).

You don't need to install CUDA at all. The OpenCL Runtime is included in the Nvidia graphics drivers already.

Comment: Do you mean to follow the link or copy the header to the source code location?

Comment: Download the headers from the link, then copy the OpenCL folder containing the headers into your source code location.