# How can install intel OpenCL integrations with visual studio?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, opencl, intel

I have tried and installed every possible combination of Intel SDK toolkits and Visual Studio (2017/19/21) in the hope that the OpenCL integrations (project templates, compiler, and header and libraries) would be added as described here:

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/quick-getting-started-guide-for-opencl-sdk-integration-in-iss-2019.html

It is not quite clear to me what toolkit is currently needed, the links to the **Intel OpenCL SDK** does not give a download link, but if found elsewehre it installs some version of an **Intel System Studio**. If trying to download the OpenCL tools I'm redirected to an **Intel oneAPI for IoT** which does not set up the bindings, and the **Base oneAPI** does not do it either.

Any help or ideas here would be appreciated?

Comment: If you just want to start developing OpenCL in Visual Studio for Intel GPUs, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57017982/9178992 You don't need to install any SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, I still would like to get the Intel oneAPI things working though.