# WIll Opencl still run on AMD gpu, if I were to write a program with OpenCL from Nvidia Vendor?

Tags: opencl, amd-gpu

So I downloaded OpenCL from Nvidia vendor, and I wrote a program. So I was wondering can my program still run on AMD GPU or I need to install AMD version of OpenCL?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

In short: Yes, programs developed with the [OpenCL headers from Nvidia toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57017982/9178992) will also work on AMD and Intel GPUs. Programs for Nvidia GPUs are always in OpenCL C 1.2, and AMD/Intel GPUs support OpenCL C 1.2/2.0/2.1/2.2, which always is backwards-compatible with OpenCL C 1.2.

---

However there are some rare issues that you could encounter, based on differences in the hardware.

One example: Nvidia GPUs work with "warps" of 32 threads, so if you choose the workgroup size 32 or a multiple of 32, you will fully use the hardware. AMD GCN GPUs need at least workgroup size 64 or a multiple of 64 to fully use the hardware. With only workgroup size 32 you only get half the arithmetic performance.

Another example: For Nvidia GPUs, you can have quite large tables still in `private` memory, and if it is too much you get a spilling into global memory (makes it very slow, but still works without error). Some AMD GPUs can't fit so many `private` variables and will throw an error during compiling, so you'd have to move the table in `constant` memory (this then works with both AMD and Nvidia).