# Cl/cl.h not found in Visual Studio Code 2019 AMD GPU Win10

Tags: windows, visual-studio, gpu, opencl, amd-gpu

I wanted to get started in GPU programming and since I have an AMD GPU I would like to start with OpenCL.

I have installed on my Windows 10 machine Visual Studio Code 2019 editor and I've also installed [OCL-SDK](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/OCL-SDK). I tried to put those variables inside the settings of VC2019 but nothing happened.

Can somebody help troubleshooting this problem? How did you manage to install OpenCL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling your code, you need to tell the linker where the OpenCL headers and lib file are located. I usually put the headers and lib file inside the project directory:

```
g++ *.cpp -o Test.exe -I./OpenCL/include -L./OpenCL/lib -lOpenCL
```

But you can also make the `-Ipath/to/OpenCL/include -Lpath/to/OpenCL/lib` paths point to the OCL-SDK directory.

For how to setup OpenCL with VS Community, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57017982/9178992

---

For an easy start with OpenCL, I created a wrapper that vastly simplifies the OpenCL C++ bindings and eliminates the entire code overhead that comes with it. This includes the OpenCL headers and all Visual Studio Community project settings; no additional setup required:
https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/OpenCL-Wrapper

Comment: Wow that’s wonderful!

Comment: I managed to resolve my problem by putting the linker folder directly in visual studio code without using the environment variable. Its a shame I didn’t manage to find your amazing project before. I’ll look how to use it.

Comment: Did I upvote correctly? I think you have really helped me/given me a suggestion/idk how to call it. Sorry but actually I think this is the first or secondth stackoverflow question