# OpenCL and Install the toolchain and GPU driver

Tags: gpu, opencl, nvidia

I would like to activate my GPU for running the Stan Bayesian on my laptop. I have no idea that how I must:

- **STEP 1:** Install the toolchain and GPU driver
- **STEP 2:** Determine the IDs of your target device

I am trying to follow this page for running on Stan Bayesian Package.
https://github.com/bstatcomp/stan_gpu_install_docs/blob/master/install_docs/INSTALL_CMDSTANR.md

Comment: What GPU model do you have? All you need is the graphics driver and OpenCL header+lib files. For the setup of Visual Studio in Windows or comping in Linux see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57017982/9178992

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I will try to follow the instruction now

Comment: Sorry, I could not find  .cpp source file. should that be your OpenCL files or I must create by myself?

Comment: Did you try following the installation steps? If yes, tell us where exactly you're struck.

Comment: Yes, I did follow the instructions. The problem is that I am running on Windows 10. I have NVIDIA GPU and Intel GPU on my system. However I just want to use NVIDIA GPU. Thus, Ineed to install Clininfo on windows which I do not knwo how I should do it.  Also, I do not know how I sould create a cpp file and cheaneg the header. I follow this link for connecting to rStan:  https://github.com/stan-dev/math/wiki/Quick-Start#enabling-gpus    I don't know how I should add Add these lines to the make/local file:
STAN_OPENCL=true
OPENCL_DEVICE_ID=${CHOSEN_INDEX}
OPENCL_PLATFORM_ID=${CHOSEN_INDEX}