# Unbale to install OpenCL in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, opencl, yum

I'm trying to install OpenCL in a CentOS 7.9 system following instructions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292630/how-to-install-opencl-in-centos-7-using-yum), but yum is unable to find the opencl-headers package as shown in my command-line output below. I tried enabling all repos as instructed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298110/centos-7-yum-install-not-working), but no luck. Can anyone help? It seems I need to point yum to the correct registry where it can find the OpenCL files. If that's correct, how do I do that? Thanks.

```
$ yum install opencl-headers

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.metrocast.net
 * centos-kernel: mirror.math.princeton.edu
 * centos-kernel-experimental: mirror.pit.teraswitch.com
 * centosplus: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * extras: distro.ibiblio.org
 * fasttrack: mirrors.wcupa.edu
 * updates: centos.mirror.constant.com
No package opencl-headers available.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`opencl-headers` package for CentOS 7 is a part of Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) repository. And this repository is not added by default, you need to add it manually. For example, using following command:

```
yum install epel-release
```

after that you will be able to install OpenCL headers using `yum` command

```
yum install opencl-headers
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to install the GPU drivers. Then your device should be detected by `clinfo`.

To develop code with OpenCL, you need the OpenCL header files. Find these [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57017982/9178992).