# Does anyone know of a linux OpenCL development environment which will support old AMD (HD7xxx) cards?

Tags: ubuntu, opencl

I used to use Ubuntu 16,18,20.04 LTS with the mesa platform but it appears to be broken. If anyone knows how to make a working environment a different way that will allow me to run OpenCL on HD7xxx and later AMD cards, that would be great. The ROCm platform doesn't support cards this old.

When I install the mesa platform, clinfo runs but with an error

```
fatal error: cannot open file '/usr/local//usr/lib/clc/tahiti-amdgcn-mesa-mesa3d.bc': No such file or directory
```

and other opencl programs fail to build. It used to work, but the path above is clearly wrong. I've tried a while ago, the bodge in which you make a soft link to the file, but then known good programs ran but produced incorrect result. Anyone know how to use OpenCL still on these old cards? Many thanks.

Comment: This works also for old AMD cards on linux: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57017982/9178992