# Is Intel OpenCL SDK available for Windows 11?

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, gpu, opencl

I want to run some C++ on my Laptop GPU with Windows 11. I saw in the Internet that I need the Intel OpenCL SDK. I tried to download it, but I got a warning that it's only recommended for Windows 10. I still continued with the installation, but i can't find all the C++ header files. Is that because I use Windows 11 or is there another reason for this?

I thought that the Download would contain all the OpenCL header files and so on.

Comment: which header files are you missing? Where have you looked?

Comment: I looked in the Directory where i installed it. It's named Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/system_studio_2020. There are the following subdirectories: documentation_2020, env.d, etc, installs, OpenCL, pset, samples_2020. It feels like the installation isn't complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the Intel OpenCL SDK for OpenCL development. All you need is the graphics driver, which probably is already present, and the OpenCL header files. For how to set it up in a Visual Studio Community project, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57017982/9178992); this works for Intel/AMD GPUs too, and on both Windows 10 and 11.