# OpenCL compiling problem at Win10 and Visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, compilation, opencl

My hardware are Intel Core I7 6700, 32 GB RAM, Nvidia GT1030. My Software are Windows 10 64bit, Visual Studio 2012 professional. I bought the book “OpenCL Parallel Programing Development Cookbook”. Unfortunately I have problems with compiling code from the book. I got compilation errors (code placed below):
Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _clGetDeviceInfo@20
Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _clGetPlatformIDs@12
Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _clGetPlatformInfo@20
Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _clGetDeviceIDs@24

```
#define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 120
#include "windows.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "CL/cl.h"
#include "malloc.h"
#include "resconsts.h"
#include <iostream> // cout
#include <fstream> // ifstream in ("test.txt") 
using namespace std; // Без этой строки не работает "static ofstream fLog()"
static ofstream fout ("logOCL_MAIN_cpp.txt");
 
typedef unsigned char Byte;

void displayPlatformInfo(cl_platform_id id, cl_platform_info param_name,
  const char* paramNameAsStr) 
{
  cl_int error = 0;
  size_t paramSize = 0;
  clGetPlatformInfo(id, param_name, 0, NULL, &paramSize);
  error = clGetPlatformInfo(id, param_name, 0, NULL, &paramSize);  
  char* moreInfo = (char*) alloca(sizeof(char)*paramSize);
  error = clGetPlatformInfo(id, param_name, paramSize, moreInfo, NULL);
  if (error != CL_SUCCESS)
    fout << "Unable to find any OpenCL Platform information";
  fout << "paramNameAsStr = " << paramNameAsStr << endl 
    << "moreInfo = " << moreInfo << endl;
}
 
void displayDeviceDetails(cl_device_id id, cl_device_info param_name,
  const char* paramNameAsStr)
{
  cl_int error = 0;
  size_t paramSize = 0;
  error = clGetDeviceInfo(id, param_name, 0, NULL, &paramSize);
  if (error != CL_SUCCESS) {
    fout << "Unable to obtain device info for param" << endl;
    return;
  } 
  // The cl_device_info are preprocessor directives defined in cl.h
  switch (param_name) {
    case CL_DEVICE_TYPE: {
      cl_device_type *devType = (cl_device_type*)alloca(sizeof(cl_device_type)*
        paramSize);
      error = clGetDeviceInfo(id, param_name, paramSize, devType, NULL);
      if (error != CL_SUCCESS) {
        fout << "Unable to obtain device info for param" << endl;
        return;
      }
      switch (*devType) {
        case CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU: {
          fout << "CPU detected" << endl;
          break;
        }
        case CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU: {
          fout << "GPU detected" << endl;
          break;
        }
        case CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT: {
          fout << "default detected" << endl;
          break;
        }
      }
      break;
    }           
  }
}
 
void displayDeviceInfo(cl_platform_id id, cl_device_type dev_type) 
{
  cl_int error = 0;
  cl_uint numOfDevices = 0;
  // Determine how many devices are connected to your platform.
  error = clGetDeviceIDs(id, dev_type, 0, NULL, &numOfDevices);
  if (error != CL_SUCCESS) {
    fout << "Unable to obtain any OpenCL compliant device info" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  cl_device_id *devices = 
    (cl_device_id*)alloca(sizeof(cl_device_id)*numOfDevices);
  // Load the information about devices into the variable "devices".
  error = clGetDeviceIDs(id, dev_type, numOfDevices, devices, NULL);
  if (error != CL_SUCCESS) {
    fout << "Unable to obtain any OpenCL compliant device info" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  fout << "Number of detected OpenCL devices = " << numOfDevices << endl;
  // We attempt to retrieve some informaion about the devices.
 
  for (int i = 0; i < numOfDevices; ++i) {
    displayDeviceDetails(devices[i], CL_DEVICE_TYPE, 
      "CL_DEVICE_TYPE");
    displayDeviceDetails(devices[i], CL_DEVICE_VENDOR_ID, 
      "CL_DEVICE_VENDOR_ID");
    displayDeviceDetails(devices[i], CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS, 
      "CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS");
    displayDeviceDetails(devices[i], CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS, 
    "CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS");
    displayDeviceDetails(devices[i], CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES, 
    "CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES");
    displayDeviceDetails(devices[i], CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, 
    "CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE");
  }
}
 
 
 
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
  LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) 
{
  cl_platform_id *platforms;
  cl_uint numOfPlatforms;
  cl_int error;
  error = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numOfPlatforms);
  if (error < 0) {
    cout << "Unable to find any OpenCL platforms" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  platforms = (cl_platform_id*) alloca (sizeof(cl_platform_id)*numOfPlatforms);
  cout << "Number of OpenCL platforms found: " << numOfPlatforms << endl;
 
  for (cl_uint i = 0; i < numOfPlatforms; ++i) {
    displayPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_PROFILE,
      "CL_PLATFORM_PROFILE");
    displayPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_VERSION,
      "CL_PLATFORM_VERSION");
    displayPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_NAME,
      "CL_PLATFORM_NAME");
    displayPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR,
      "CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR");
    displayPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS,
      "CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I did try SDK from KhronosGroup, I did try “OpenCL-Wrapper-master”, I did try CUDA ToolKit from Nvidia. I need instruction, “How to” compile some OpenCL host’s and device’s program by Visual Studio 2012 Professional.

Comment: "Visual Studio 2012" - Why use an 11+ year old IDE?

Comment: Your problem appears to be your linker settings. You need to link to the library that implements `_clGetDeviceIDs` Did you add the linker setting to make `Opencl.lib` a dependency?

Comment: I did add "OpenCL.lib" in "project settings->C/C++->Command line" and I got new errors (listed below) instead of former errors.

1>  OpenCL.lib
1>OpenCL.lib(1): error C2059: syntax error : '<'
1>OpenCL.lib(2): error C2018: unknown character '0x60'
1>OpenCL.lib(3): error C2018: unknown character '0x6'
1>OpenCL.lib(3): error C2059: syntax error : 'bad suffix on number'
1>OpenCL.lib(3): error C2470: 'r' : looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body
1>OpenCL.lib(3): error C2059: syntax error : ':'...

Comment: You need to add the library in `Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies` and not `C/C++->Command line`

Comment: See here for which Linker settings to add: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57017982/9178992